# Selecting records with N fields from a file

Tags: scripting, csh, tcsh

can somebody help me, how can I  filter my file, inside the file I have rows with 3, 4, 5 elements, I want print using echo only these which have 5 elements, thanks in advance (I'm talkin about scripts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat $file | awk '(NF==5) { print $0}'`

Comment: Charles Stewart: sorry, but is it possible to find another way? I'm working with c-shell

Comment: @lego69: That *is* csh: two Unix calls, one pipeline, one variable substitution. What's the problem?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: I love cats.  Feel lucky I spared you twins: cat $file | cat | awk ...